# Error thrown file does not exist even though it is there

Tags: hibernate

Here's my code structure :

[image: HelloWorld]

And here's the insert code from DAO :

```
public void insert(String name) {  

    Resource r=new ClassPathResource("app.xml");  
    BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(r);  

    EmployeeDao dao=(EmployeeDao)factory.getBean("d");  

    Employee e=new Employee();  
    e.setId(114);  
    e.setName(name);  
    e.setSalary(50000);  

    dao.saveEmployee(e);  

}
```

I get this error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [app.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [app.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist`.

I tried closing the project and opening it, cleaning it and building it, but nothing works. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify the path to the `app.xml`

```
Resource r = new ClassPathResource("main/java/db/app.xml");
```

The reason of the error: the resource is loaded by  `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`, not by `Class.getResourceAsStream()`.

The same reason is for a forward `/` absence.