# IllegalArgument exception

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am trying hibernate+Spring for the first time and getting this error while trying to insert into DB. The String is coming from the url or a default value :-

```
    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {

    InsertTest test = new InsertTest();
    test.insert(name);
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                        String.format(template, name));
}
```

And the DAO method is :-

```
    public void insert(String name) { 

    Resource r=new ClassPathResource("D:\\work\\Spring\\RestAPI\\src\\main\\java\\db\\app.xml");  
    BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(r);  

    EmployeeDao dao=(EmployeeDao)factory.getBean("d");  

    Employee e=new Employee();  
    e.setId(114);  
    e.setName(name);  
    e.setSalary(50000);  

    dao.saveEmployee(e);  

}
```

And I am getting error:-

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$Loader.findResource(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.findResource(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:58) ~[gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar:0.1.0]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResourceAsStream(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1055) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:166) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:79) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:67) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at main.java.db.InsertTest.insert(InsertTest.java:21) ~[classes!/:0.1.0]
    at main.java.hello.GreetingController.greeting(GreetingController.java:23) ~[classes!/:0.1.0]
```

Comment: [edit] your question and include the full stack trace. The next few lines will tell you exactly which line the error is on.

Comment: My assumption is that `name` is either null or empty, and the exception is thrown on `e.setName(name);`, if this is the case, debug and do simple validations on the value, before passing it to the method.

Comment: I have debugged prior sending it to the method, Its showing "World" if nothing is passed in URL. Also, I am adding the stacktrace

Comment: how are you calling this rest endpoint?

Comment: Provide a name query string parameter with http://localhost:8080/greeting?name=JohnDoe OR default :  http://localhost:8080/greeting

Comment: Please stop and step back from the keyboard... You shouldn't be creating a new `beanFactory` or `ApplicationContext` you should use dependency injection. Your `InsertTest` should be a bean which gets the `EmployeeDao` injected. General rule of thumb as soon as you start creating a `BeanFactory` or `ApplicationContext` outside of a `main` method you are probably doing the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem as in your previous question (next time just ask for clarifications in the comments):

[Error thrown file does not exist even though it is there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44072301/error-thrown-file-does-not-exist-even-though-it-is-there)

You need to specify this path:

```
Resource r = new ClassPathResource("main/java/db/app.xml");
```

This is not a file system path, but a path that begins from the root package.